# Is data log the only form to save data?can we record our data in another way based on modern operating systems?

Tags: mysql, database, filesystems, datastore

so many database systems use data log file to eventually save data,such as MySQL,MongoDB etc.Is there any other available way, which if possible has the same performance as prevailing database systems to record data?

I've tried to search in books and google, but there seems to be little discussion about this issue, or maybe I haven't found the right book yet?

Comment: What does the data look like?  Where does it come from?  After collecting it, what will you do with the data?  Any RDBMS (eg MySQL) shines when doing complex queries (lookups, tallies, etc) on the collected data.